# Visual Studio TSQL numbers not visible

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, text, editor

I'm using Visual Sudio 2010 and I have a .sql file. I've edited my environment text by doing tools -> options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors then in Text Editor I edited my environment to have a black background.  I already have gone through the text editor and changed the forground color to non-blacks, but I am having an issue with the forground color of TSQL digits being black text.

For example say I had pi() / 20 then I wouldn't see 20 because it's black like the background.

My question is does anyone know how I can fix this?  I have been up and down the Text Editor font/color options a bunch, and I don't see where I can fix this setting problem.

I hate staring at white screens so I'd prefer not to have to restore default colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below worked for me.

Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts & Colors -> Under Display Items select 'Number', and choose a non-black color -> Click OK

Comment: For me it wasn't called Select Number, but just Number.  But it was close enough I was able to find it thanks.

Comment: Actually I meant 'Number' only :), edited answer to make it clear.